# df1 subtract df2 not working as expected in Pyspark when the records are not in order

Tags: python, dataframe, hadoop, pyspark

I have 2 files. In one `file1` I have `998` records and in another `file2`, I have `1000` records. Now, when I try `df1.subtract(df2)` it gives `998` records and when I try `df2.subtract(df1)` it gives `1000` as the count. I also compared it manually in excel. All the records are same the except the additional records in `file2`. So, the `expected` output for `df2.subtract(df1)` should be 2. Where am I going wrong? Is there any way to match two data frames irrespective of its rows order?

`df1`:

[image]

`df2`:
[image]

**First Approach**:

```
df1 = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("Sales_records-1.csv")
df2 = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("Sales_records-2.csv")


#Finding the rows which are not present in second dataframe
df3 = df2.exceptAll(df1)
```

Comment: Do you need to count `1000-998` or how many values are different in those files?

Comment: Values are the same if you maintain the order of rows in both the files. I should get 2 when I try `df2.subtract(df1)` because `df2` is created by reading `file2` and it has 2 more records

Comment: `df2.except(df1)`

Comment: `except` works in `scala` not in Python. for Python, its `exceptAll` but even that returns the same result.

Comment: Show your sample for each df.

Comment: Added the screenshots. It's a sample data, not the entire one.

Comment: No image. I cannot copy them. BTW, I have tested with my own test data and works fine. You should check the schema is same for all and records too.

Comment: Schema is entirely the same for these files as well as records are also the same.. it's just that 2nd file has 2 more records...and subtract returns wrong result..do I need to do something explicitly. Even I checked if the order is same then it works fine..

Comment: Even I checked if the order is the same then it works fine.Can I use `HashSet` or something in order to find the different records?

Comment: Can you add a piece of code showing how you load those files?

Comment: I have added two approaches that I tried and didn't work. @mazaneicha Please have a glance once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I found that my data had `unique ID` and I used the below code to `find different records` when the `counts are different in two datasets`. If the counts are different in two datasets, in-built methods like `subtract` or `exceptAll` won't work. I even tried various types of `joins` but didn't work out. You may have to do something similar like I did.

```
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("temp2")
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("temp1")

spark.sql("select * from temp2 where `Order ID` not in (select `Order ID` from temp1)").show()
```

So, this gives me the 2 records that I had been looking for from `df2.subtract(df1)`

Hope this approach will help someone someday!